# Is there a way I can download a file coming from props, in my react app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically, in my use case, I'm receiving File Object from Parent to the Download component through the props and I want to be able to straight away download it. Is there a way I can do that ?

Please find below reference. [*I know, it looks a bit weird in Parent component to select file using file input and to be able to download it just then. This is just for the sake of simplicity.*]

Download Button

```
const DocumentMessage = ({file, type, label, ...props}) => {
 return (
    <Button as='a' style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} target='_blank' href={file} {...props}>{label}</Button>
 );
}
```

Example of Parent Component where it's used -

```
export const documentMessageDefault = () => {
 const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
 const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
 }
 return (
    <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <DocumentMessage file={selectedFile} label= 'Download File' />
    </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: You can't do that directly, The file object can't be used as a value for the `href` attribute, instead, you have to upload the file to the server and then use the path of the file to be download, and use the download attribute, check this links 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a
https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly people are uploading a file to you and then you want to offer them the option to download their own file?

Comment: @mostafatourad you can base64 encode the file and combined with the mimetype you can add it as a value to the href attribute. Combine this with the download attribute and you can download directly

Comment: @Tschallacka Yes but I think this will not work with all files. If you think it works, can you please show me the snippet because I tried it and it only works with images.

Comment: @mostafatourad It works for any type, as long as you have a lookup table/array for the correct mimetypes. I don't have the time to write the code in javascript, but this is the code in php https://gist.github.com/tschallacka/ddb63a31edcf768e40beb70c32ce5c6c